# encrypt with php and failed decrypt aes-256-cbc with java

Tags: java, php, encryption, aes

i have the problam, in existing code encrypt code using php.
this is code for encrypt with php langunage :

```
<?PHP
  $token = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";

  $cipher_method = 'aes-256-cbc';
  $enc_key = openssl_digest("keyssss", 'SHA256', TRUE);
  $enc_iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher_method));
  $crypted_token = openssl_encrypt($token, $cipher_method, $enc_key, 0, $enc_iv) . "::" . bin2hex($enc_iv);
  unset($token, $cipher_method, $enc_key, $enc_iv);
?>
```

but, if i want to decode with java always failed :

this is java code :

```
@GetMapping("/verify")
    public String tokenFB(@RequestParam("accessToken") String accessToken) {

        try {
            String[] accessTokenSplit = accessToken.split("::");
            if (accessTokenSplit.length < 2) {
                throw new BadRequestException("accessTokenInvalid");
            }
            String token = accessTokenSplit[0];
            String iv = accessTokenSplit[1];
            byte[] tokenByte = Base64.getDecoder().decode(token);

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            SecretKey secretKey = makeKey();
            IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = makeIv(iv);

            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivParameterSpec);
            byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(tokenByte);

            return new String(plainText);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private IvParameterSpec makeIv(String iv) {
        byte[] ivHex = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(iv);
        return new IvParameterSpec(ivHex);
    }

    private SecretKey makeKey() {
        try {
            MessageDigest dg = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            byte[] keyByte = dg.digest("secretKeys".getBytes());
            return new SecretKeySpec(keyByte, "AES");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

the error is `Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.`

how to be decrypt with java languange ?

**Solved**

Comment: In the PHP code, ciphertext and IV are concatenated (with separator `::`). Where does the separation take place in the Java code or what is `"enc_iv"` in the `makeIv()` method?

Comment: oh, sorry, it's just example, so i set manual for iv and key.

java code already update with separator (::) yah.. thank you @Topaco

Comment: In the Java code, the ciphertext must of course be Base64 _decoded_ before decryption and not Base64 encoded: `byte[] tokenByte = Base64.getDecoder().decode(token);`. Furthermore, PKCS#7 padding must be used: `Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");`. Then decryption with the Java code works.

Comment: oh, already try,.

but when decode the token error `Illegal base64 character 20` @Topaco

Comment: updated..
 thank you @Topaco 

already solve, token must be send to json body, if token send with get params failed..